# Linked List and pointer clarification

Tags: java, linked-list

In the Cracking the Coding Interview Linked List question:
Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list, the solution is

```
public static void deleteDups (LinkedListNode n){
  Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
  LinkedListNode previous = null;
  while(n!=null){
      if(table.containsKey(n.data)){
          previous.next = n.next;
      } else {
          table.put(n.data, true);
          previous = n;
      }
      n = n.next;
  }
}
```

My question is why does `n = n.next` not alter the linked list passed into the function, but doing `previous.next = n.next` and `previous = n` do alter the linked list passed in?

Comment: Aside: if you use a `Hashtable` in a modern Java interview, you will likely do poorly.

Answer (score 5):

`n` is a reference to a `LinkedListNode`. By setting a different value there, you don't modify the original `LinkedListNode`, just change a reference from it to something else. In other words, you "remember" something new under the label "n", but you do not modify the original "n".

```
X x = new X();
x = new X(); // this does not modify the original x
```

`previous` is the `LinkedListNode` and by setting a value OF that LinkedListNode, you are modifying it.

```
X x = new X();
x.y = new Y(); // this does mofiy the original x
```

In other words, you are setting a property of the value you remembered as "previous".

And, as dimo414 already mentioned, using HashTable here is a bad idea. Clarity alone should be enough reason to use a simple (Hash-)Set.

Answer (score 1):

n is the pointer to the relevant linked list node.

```
n = n.next
```

simply moves the pointer to the next node.

```
previous.next = n.next
```

changes where the node "previous" points.  previous.next is a value contained in object "previous", the node after previous.  So previous.next = n.next modifies the "previous" node object.